# ios app based on Firebase database - to incorporate changes locally

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In an iOS app, developed using [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start),  can a user make changes to database on his/her device that is reflected only locally on his/her device?

My app is a contacts app and I want any user be able to edit or favourite a contact which should be only reflected on his/her device and not to every user using the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading up on structuring data in Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data

(When you're done, read all the docs or perhaps follow some video tutorials on Firebase.)

This will help you establish a better understanding of how Firebase works, helping you with more than just the problem at hand.